# Pass dragged filename to Windows shortcut

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts

I want to create a shortcut for a command line tool, so that when I drag files onto it, it will pass the filename to the tool as part of the command line arguments (with quotations around it or whatever so that paths with spaces work), and then keep the terminal open after it has finished.  Specifically:

```
cmd /k "C:\Program Files (x86)\SRecord\bin\srec_info.exe" "%<something goes here>" --guess
```

Is this possible?  What goes after the percent sign?  What's this called?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simply:

```
cmd /k "C:\Program Files (x86)\SRecord\bin\srec_info.exe" "%1"
```

This will pass the path to the file. To test this we can make a simple receiver bat file `test.bat`:

```
echo %1
pause
```

Drag in "C:\Users\user\Desktop\nospaces.exe",
result:

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\nospaces.exe
```

Drag in "C:\Users\user\Desktop\file with spaces.exe",
result:

```
"C:\Users\user\Desktop\file with spaces.exe"
```

So srec_info.exe should receive the path+filename in the same way the bat file did.

Comment: Ok, that's for batch files, though.  Is there a way to do it in shortcuts?

Comment: "test.bat %1" and "srec_info.exe %1" should function in the same way. I clarified the answer.

Comment: Yes, but I tried that already and it didn't work.  :)  I can use a batch file, though.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question properly. The OP specifically mentions a "shortcut", not a batch file.

Comment: What? The first line is the shortcut you would use. The batfile is just a test case.